# React - Getting refs to wrapped class components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, higher-order-components

I have a map component that contains a child sidebar component. I am trying to do a relatively simple task of scrolling to the place in the list of places in the sidebar when it's map marker is clicked on. But, because the sidebar needs to be wrapped in `withRouter` and `connect`, I'm unable to set a ref `(ref) => this.sidebar = ref` in the map component.

```
export class Map extends React.Component {
  ...

  handleClick() {
    this.sidebar.scrollToPlace(place.id);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <MapSidebar
        // unable to set ref
      />
    )
  }
}
```

and

```
class MapSidebar extends React.Component {
  ...

  scrollToPlace(id) {
    this.refs[id].scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapSidebar));
```

I know that using `wrappedComponentRef` could get me the contents of `withRouter`, but then I still have `connect` to deal with.

I also tried creating a custom ref on the `MapSidebar` instance:

```
<MapSidebar
  getReference={(ref) => {
    this.sidebar = ref;
  }} />
```

and then in the `MapSidebar` class constructor, calling:

```
if(this.props.getReference) {
  this.props.getReference(this);
}
```

but that resulted in an infinite loop of that component updating (although I'm not sure I understand why).

Is there a better way to get around these issues?

Comment: Have you looked into the npm package `react-waypoint`?

Comment: @Andrew how would you propose using this package to solve my problem? It looks like it's core use is to execute functions when you scroll to a certain dom element.

Comment: Apologies, I meant `react-scroll`

Comment: 1.connect of redux? why not set selected one in store and pass it through connect. 2.in redux connect,`this.refs.xx.getWrappedInstance()` will return the wrappped one, and withRouter should be likely the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you avoid refs and simply pass the scroll value down:

```
export class Map extends React.Component {
  ...

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({scrollToPlaceId: place.id});
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <MapSidebar
        // Add a new property
        scrollToPlace={this.state.scrollToPlaceId}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Then in your sidebar component, just listen to scroll changes in `componentWillReceiveProps` for example

```
class MapSidebar extends React.Component {
  ...

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.scrollToPlace !== this.props.scrollToPlace) {
      this.refs[nextProps.scrollToPlace].scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
  }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapSidebar));
```

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference in both classes:

```
// MapSidebar render - add this to the element you want.
<div ref={r => (this.ref = r)}>
```

Then in Map render:

```
<MapSidebar ref={r => (this.sidebar = r)}>
```

Now after Map has mounted you have access to the ref:

```
this.sidebar.ref
```